# Android GreenDao Update a single field with condition

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, greendao

I am new with greenDao (version 3). I have a table with a status field. I have a list of IDs. I want to update all of status to 'active' with IDs. I failed to get the any such method for this update. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create the list using query builder as you normal would to select items. Once you have that you can use

```
itemsList.get(i).setStatus("active");
```

But this won't update the actual dao until you use

```
 getDaoSession().getItemsDao().update(itemsList.get(i));
```

Comment: Keep in mind your dao will need to have a primary key in place or this will cause an error